# How can I Display a wizard link without a category or display a category above General category in eclipse importWizard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Using https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_my_wizard_to_the_New,_Import,_or_Export_menu_categories%3F document I was able to create a category on Eclipse ImportWizard and add my Item to it.

My problem is I want to Display my Category(or item) above General category on ImportWizard.

Note: the way Eclipse order categories on ImportWizard is first they display General category followed by rest of the categories in alphabetical order and at last the Other category.

Is it possible to either display my category above all categories (including General Category) or display my Wizard link as the top element in the Eclipses' ImportWizard? If so please let me know how.

Note:
ImportWizard is the wizard you get when you click File->Import on Eclipse
Categories are the folders on that Wizards first page
Items are the entries on each Category. i.e. "Java" category has item "Java Project"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of rewriting the Import command handler and the `ImportExportWizard`, `ImportPage` and `ImportExportPage` classes this does not appear to be possible.

The actual ordering of the import tree is done by the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.DataTransferWizardCollectionComparator` which is hard coded to put the General category first (and the Other category last).

Comment: Thanks mate, You are right it look like it is hard coded. It look like I am stuck in the middle :)